# data.table not updating by reference anymore

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a function

```
f <- function(orderData){
        colNames <- paste0("lim_",sort(unique(orderData[,XLM])))
        orderData[, (colNames):={lim_=factor(XLM);lapply(data.table(model.matrix(~ lim_:w_qalim + 0)), cumsum)}]
}
```

and some sample data

```
dt = data.table(XLM=sample(1L:300L,5e4,T), w_qalim=sample(1L:5L,5e4,T))
dt1 = data.table(XLM=sample(1L:300L,1e2,T), w_qalim=sample(1L:5L,1e2,T))
```

Executing `f(dt)` does not update `dt` by reference on my box but `f(dt1)` do. Is it expected/ something to do with `datatable.alloccol`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases the length of the data table is 2 and the truelength is 100:

```
> length(dt); truelength(dt)
[1] 2
[1] 100
> length(dt1); truelength(dt1)
[1] 2
[1] 100
```

however, in the case of `dt` `colNames` is 300 so 2+300 exceeds the truelength but in the case of `dt1` `colNames` is 81 so 2+81 does not.

You can either allocate a larger truelength in advance, e.g.

```
alloc.col(dt, 1000)
```

or you can set the default so that all data tables have a larger default:

```
options(datatable.alloccol = 1000)
```

See `?alloc.col` ,

Comment: Ok so I guess I was ok to think a copy was done when I was creating too many colums. Thanks for pointing out ?alloc.col